# Reduce multi-level array into object

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
[
    ["123", { keyOne: "val", keyTwo: "val2" }],
    ["402", { keyOne: "val123", keyTwo: "val233" }],
    ["542", { keyOne: "val", keyTwo: "val2" }],
];
```

And I need to turn it into an Object like this:

```
{
    "123": { keyOne: "val", keyTwo: "val2" },
    "402": { keyOne: "val123", keyTwo: "val233" },
    "542": { keyOne: "val", keyTwo: "val2" }
}
```

I think this should be done with [**reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) , but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const data = [
    ["123", { keyOne: "val", keyTwo: "val2" }],
    ["402", { keyOne: "val123", keyTwo: "val233" }],
    ["542", { keyOne: "val", keyTwo: "val2" }],
];

const result = Object.fromEntries(data);

console.log(result);
```